# Eclipse debug mode introduces unwanted synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to diagnose convoluted multithreading operations in java.
I want to use the debug perspective to do so, but I encounter the following issue :

Expected behavior :
When pausing a thread (through the Debug view), the "Variables" view should show the variables
as seen by the thread I paused.
Using the Step over / step into operation multiple times should not modify variables in the thread.

Code (Using java 17):

```java
package fr.fgoux.debugbugdemo;

public class DebugDemoMain
{
    public int t;

    public DebugDemoMain()
    {
        this.t = 0;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final DebugDemoMain demo = new DebugDemoMain();
        final Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    } catch (final InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    demo.t++;
                }
                System.out.println("Write terminated");
            }
        });
        final Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while (demo.t != 100)
                {

                }
                System.out.println("READ terminated");
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try
        {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (final InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("END");
    }

}
```

Behavior :
When I run this in debug mode, I get the output :

```
Write terminated
```

And the other thread keeps running.

If I pause the running thread, the debugger shows me it's stuck at "while (demo.t != 100)".
But the "variables" tab shows me t=100.
If I resume / pause this thread, it stays at the "while (demo.t != 100)" and keeps running.

If I press a step by step button, the thread execution line jumps out of the while loop, and then If I resume execution, the thread terminates with "READ terminated".

Personnal interpretation :

The reading thread that does the "demo.t != 100" caches the variable demo.t so that it does not notice that the other thread changed demo.t value (which is expected since there is no synchronization). It cannot make progress.

The "Variables" view does not show locally cached variables of the thread, but only some global representation of the variables (maybe in the shared memory).

The step by step operations cause the thread to update it's cache from the shared memory.

Question :
Is there a better debugging tool that would allow me to show these cached variables and diagnose these issues ?

Comment: Well, the first rule is to not write convoluted multi-threaded code in the first place.  I'm not joking about that, it's basically an impossible situation to deal with.  The code itself is the problem, you have to fix that.  For monitoring variables that other threads are changing, I don't really have a solution for that, it's just not practical.  I think the best solution would be to instrument the code itself (use logging statements for example) so that you can locate problems as they occur.

Comment: `demo` is `final`, but its field `t` is not `volatile` and there is no synchronization. So thread `t2` might not seeing the changes done in thread `t1`. The _Variables_ view shows the values that are reported by the Java VM via the [Java Debug Wire Protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jdwp/jdwp-spec.html) to the IDE.

Comment: Logging statement usually involve some kind of synchronized code, which will induce flushing of the thread cache and thus hide the problem. Even if you can somehow avoid that, any logging will anyway induce delays and make reproducibility worse.

Comment: I see what you mean, it would be nice to know what local values are in each thread. But these values cannot be accessed by debugging. Probably because it would be more complex for the Java VM and would prevent optimization during just-in-time compilation of the bytecode, which would make the Java VM slower. However, the code is not deterministic, it can behave differently. I guess in most cases, in `t2` `demo.t` will be `0` because synchronization is avoided for performance reasons, but there is no guarantee for that.